# how to check find command list of files if no files then exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Hi I am using find command in my scrpt to get list of log files modified in one day and using the list to grep. But if there is no file found then its not comingout of shell. Can I use any if conditions to check before using the command. If yes how to check it.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep 'EXSTAT|' $(find . -mtime 0 -type f)|grep '|S|'|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"|" '{a[$11]++;c[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a){print b"," a[b]","c[b]/a[b]}}'
```

I tried only grep below but no response and I have to terminate by CTRL+C.

```
bash-3.2$ ls -ltr
total 126096
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10486146 Sep  4 09:20 ivrbroker.log.6
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10486278 Sep  9 14:45 ivrbroker.log.5
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10492782 Sep 14 14:54 ivrbroker.log.4
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10487657 Sep 16 13:17 ivrbroker.log.3
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10486437 Oct 29 10:26 ivrbroker.log.2
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    10485955 Nov 17 11:28 ivrbroker.log.1
-rw-r-----   1 tibco    tibco    1537673 Nov 18 08:48 ivrbroker.log

bash-3.2$ find . -mtime 0 -type f
bash-3.2$ grep 'EXSTAT|' $(find . -mtime 0 -type f)
#!/bin/bash
bnkpath=/tibcouat1_fs/tibco/deployment/egypt/bnk/broker/logs/
file_list=$(find $bnkpath -mtime 0 -type f)
if [ -z $file_list ]; then
echo "No log file found"
else
echo "log file found"
grep 'EXSTAT|' $(find $file_list -mtime 0 -type f)|grep '|S|'|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"|" '{a[$11]++;c[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a){print b"," a[b]","c[b]/a[b]}}'
fi
bash-3.2$ ./bnk1.sh          
./bnk1.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
log file found
```

Answer (score 0):

The grep command is holding the terminal because the find command returns NO file name. This will effectively have the same impact as executing

```
grep 'EXSTAT|'
```

This is because grep is expecting some input for itself to execute, if no input is given(as in this case), it looks for STDIN for some input.

As a simple quick solution you may try splitting the find and grep commands. Something like this will work

```
file_list=$(find . -mtime 0 -type f)
! [ -z $file_list ] || grep 'EXSTAT|' $file_list |grep '|S|'|/usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"|" '{a[$11]++;c[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a){print b"," a[b]","c[b]/a[b]}}'
```

will do.

Comment: I added condition in script     if [ -z $file_list ]; then
    echo "No log file found"
    else
    echo "log file found" but getting too many argument on screen after that output

Comment: You forget to add fi. The end of if ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your script & applied some modification.

1. You need to utilize FOR loop as file_list is an array of files.
2. utilize -maxdepth to make sure you don't look inside other directory
3. Line 4 Error is coming as you forgot double quotes

> ```
> bnkpath=/tibcouat1_fs/tibco/deployment/egypt/bnk/broker/logs/
> file_list=$(find $bnkpath -maxdepth 1 -mtime 0 -type f)
> if [ -z "$file_list" ]
> then
>         echo "No log file found"
> else
>         echo "log file found"
>         for i in $file_list;
>         do
>         grep 'EXSTAT|' $i | grep '|S|' | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk -F"|" '{a[$11]++;c[$11]+=$14}END{for(b in a){print b"," a[b]","c[b]/a[b]}}'
>         done 
> fi
> ```